Showing $L^2$ - convergence of $\phi_n(X_n)$ to $\phi(X)$ when $\phi_n \to \phi$ and $X_n\to X$
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of square integrable random variables converging to $X$ in $L^2$ and $(\phi_n)$ a sequence of smooth functions converging to $\phi$ uniformly on compact sets where $\phi$ is $C^1$ and Lipschitz. Then i want to show that
$$\phi_n(X_n) \to \phi(X)$$
in $L^2$. My idea was to use Minkowski's inequality
$$\mathbb{E}[(\phi_n(X_n)-\phi(X))^2]^{1/2} \le \mathbb{E}[(\phi_n(X_n)-\phi(X_n))^2]^{1/2} + \mathbb{E}[(\phi(X)-\phi(X_n))^2]^{1/2}$$
where we second term goes to $0$ since $\phi$ is Lipschitz and the $X_n$'s converge. However, I'm not sure what to do about the first term. My hunch is that you need to restrict to $X_n$ being in a compact set, use the uniform convergence here and then somehow extend this, but I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's the correct strategy. Any help is much appreciated.
EDIT: A counter example has been provided if the assumptions are as above. If we in addition assume that all $\phi_n$ as bounded in the following way for all $n$
$$|\phi_n(x)|\le c(1+|x|),$$
is this then enough for the result to hold?

Hint: for any $x$ you have $|\phi_{n}(x) - \phi(x)| \leq \lVert \phi_{n} - \phi\rVert_{\infty}$, now what does uniform convergence tell us?

@RaulFernandesHorta Uniform convergence is by definition that the sup-norm goes to $0$, but I don't see how I can use this here, since I only have uniform convergence on compact sets, so for any $k>0$, I know that
$\sup_{x\in [-k,k]} |\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. How do I get something independent of $k$?

You will have to break the expected value in two parts, choose $k$ large enough such that de probability of $|X_n| > k$ is small for big $n$ (this happens because convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in measure), but you need to be careful in the order you choose those things

@RaulFernandesHorta I'm not sure this is enough. The part where $|X|\le k$ goes to $0$ then, and since the sequence $(X_n)$ is tight, for any $\epsilon>0$ you can choose $k$ large enough such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>k)<\epsilon$ for all $n$. However, you still need to control $|\phi_n(X_n)-\phi(X_n)|^2$ inside the expectation, and it's not clear to me that this is possible.

This is not necessarily the case. Assume your probability space is the standard $((0,1), \mathcal L)$ ($\mathcal L$ is the lebesgue measure) and define the random variables $X_n$ as follows:
$$X_n(x):=\begin{cases}n&\text{ if $x\in \left[1-\frac1{n^4},1\right]$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$.
Now clearly $\mathbb E(|X_n|^2)=\frac1{n^2}$, hence $X_n\to 0$.
Now let $\varphi_0$ be a bump function such that

$\varphi_0\equiv 1$ on $\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]$
$\text{supp}(\varphi_0)\subseteq \left[-\frac34,\frac34\right]$
$0\le \varphi_0(x)\le 1$ for any $x$.

Define $\varphi_n(x):=2^n\varphi(x-n)$. Clearly, $\varphi_n\to 0$ uniformly on compact sets. However, $\varphi_n(X_n(x))$ equals $2^n$ for $x\in \left[1-\frac1{n^4},1\right]$, hence it does not converge in $L^2$.
Edit: To answer you question in the comments: if we assume that the functions $\varphi_n$ have uniformly bounded growth like $|\varphi_n(x)|\le C( 1+|x|)$, then the answer is positive.
Proof:
Clearly we also have $|\varphi(x)|\le C(1+|x|)$. As you noticed, it suffices to estimate
$\mathbb E(|\varphi_n(X_n)-\varphi(X_n)|^2)$.
To lighten the notation, let me write $Z_n:=\varphi_n(X_n)-\varphi(X_n)$.
Assume by extracting a subsequence that we have convergence almost everywhere. Notice that
$$|Z_n|^2\le 4C^2(1+|X_n|)^2$$
then apply Fatou to $4C^2(1+|X_n|)^2-|Z_n|^2\ge 0$ (in the following, let $K=4C^2$):
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E(K(1+|X|)^2)-\limsup \mathbb E(|Z_n|^2)&=
\liminf \mathbb  E(K(1+|X_n|)^2 -|Z_n)|^2)\\&\ge \mathbb E(\liminf K(1+|X_n|)^2-|Z_n|^2)\\&=\mathbb E(K(1+X)^2).
\end{align}$$
It follows that
$$\limsup \mathbb E(|Z_n|^2)\le 0,$$
proving the result.
Final note: the trick I have used above is folklore and can be summarised as follows: let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $L^1$ converging pointwise to $f$ and assume that there exists a sequence $g_n$ of functions converging pointwise and in $L^1$ to $g$ such that $|f_n|\le g_n$. Then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$. You can think of this as a strengthened version of the DCT (where we take $g_n$ constant)

This doesn't seem right. The expectation of $X_n^2$ is $n^2(1-1/n^4) = \frac{n^4-1}{n^2}$ which does not go to $0$. I guess you wanted the lower endpoint to be $1-\frac{1}{n^4}$? But I guess you're right. I think maybe I'm missing an assumption then.
What if we require that there exists $c>0$ such that  for all $n$, $|\phi_n(x)| \le c(1+|x|)$?
The result is part of the proof of proposition 1.2.7 in Markus Kunze's introduction to Malliavin calculus: https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/kunze/malliavin/Malliavin_skript.pdf

@Snildt Yeah, I got the lower endpoint wrong, I'll fix it.

@Snildt I have added a proof that, with the additional hypothesis you stated on the growth of $\varphi_n$, we do indeed have $L^2$ convergence. Hope that helps

Wow, I didn't expect it to be this simple! A final question, just to be sure - we can assume that the convergence of $(X_n)$ holds almost surely because otherwise we could use that a sequence convergences if and only if any subsequence has a further subsequence with the same limit? Because then we could extract a subsequence converging a.e and then use your proof?

@Snildt Exactly
